# Unit Testing a custom ElasticSearch Client with JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, elasticsearch

I have created a custom Elastic Search Client. I need to deploy unit testing on the various functions. How should I do that?

Say for example , in JUnit I use these ->

```
assertEquals(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
```

The problem here is that there is actually no return value. The queries execute and manipulate things. I want to unit test the various functions.

For example, I want to see if the index() works properly. I don't really want to actually index data and check if it has been indexed as I am not doing the integration testing right now. Can I do just unit testing?

Following is a method from my client. How should I deploy unit testing here?

```
@Override
        public ActionFuture<IndexResponse> index(IndexRequest request)
            {
                TimerContext indexTimerContext=indexTimer.time();
                super.index(request));
                indexTimerContext.stop();
            }
```

How should I really go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

ElasticSearch has its own [Test Framework](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/testing-framework.html) and ( [assertion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/assertions.html) )
tutorial describes unit and integration testing!
If you want to use other framework you could use **mockito** or **easymock**. In your case you have to check that method `index(IndexRequest request)` calls `indexTimer.time()` and 
`indexTimerContext.stop()` therefore you must mock `indexTimer` and
verify call. look at [Java verify void method calls n times with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787487/java-verify-void-method-calls-n-times-with-mockito)

**EDIT**
I have never work with ElasticSearch, but your unit test will look like this

```
@Test
public void testIndex() {

    clientTest = Mockito.spy(new MyClient());
    //this is a field, which we mock
    IndexTimer indexTimerSpy = Mockito.spy(new IndexTimer());
    //TimerContext we mock too
    TimerContext timerContextSpy = Mockito.spy(new TimerContext());
    //IndexTimer.time returns our timer context
    Mockito.doReturn(timerContextSpy).when(indexTimerSpy).time();
    //set indexTimer
    clientTest.setIndexTimer(indexTimerSpy);
    //calls method under test
    clientTest.index(null);
    //verify calls of methods
    Mockito.verify(indexTimerSpy).time();
    Mockito.verify(timerContextSpy).stop();

    // Prevent/stub logic when calling super.index(request) 
    //Mockito.doNothing().when((YourSuperclass)clientTest).index();

}
```

Comment: Should I mock  indexTimer or indexTmerContext?

the time() is returning a new instance of timerContext ["new TimerContext(this, clock)" ]

Comment: You have to mock all objects indexTimer indexTimerContext and your class. I have edit my answer. I think my example is clear

Comment: The elasticsearch Test Frameworks is equal to nothing. Not a very useful thing. Where can I find proper examples?