# How to verify a method which was called multiple times

Tags: mockito, junit4

I am working on JUNIT, where i need to verify a method whether it is called or not. so i added below code

```
verify(mock).method();
```

When i run i am getting below exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
mock.method();
Wanted 1 time:
But was 36 times:
```

I understand it was invoked 36 times but wanted only one time. help me in fixing this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify a method is called two times with mockito verify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889951/how-to-verify-a-method-is-called-two-times-with-mockito-verify)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Mockito` you can do that by specifying that your method should be called atleast once.

**For example:**

```
verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).method();
```

For more information: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787487/java-verify-void-method-calls-n-times-with-mockito)

Comment: @basky If this answer worked for you. Can you please accept it. It will help others on community to resolve same issue.