# Mockito validates already verified invocations

Tags: java, mockito

```
static class Foo {
    public void bar(int i) {}
}

@Test
public void foo() {
    Foo f = Mockito.spy(new Foo());
    f.bar(42);
    Mockito.verify(f, Mockito.times(1)).bar(42);
    f.bar(42);
    Mockito.verify(f, Mockito.times(1)).bar(42);
}
```

causes `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations` (wanted 1 time, but was 2) on last line. Running it in debug shows, that `InvocationMatcher` ignores the fact that first invocation was already verified. And it does not depend on witch exactly matcher is passed into `bar`. Am I doing something wrong, or it is a bug of Mockito?

Comment: Why not seperating it in 2 different test cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify a method is called two times with mockito verify()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889951/how-to-verify-a-method-is-called-two-times-with-mockito-verify)

Comment: @Joe I think it's not duplicate because the OP is verifying the same method twice. Have you tried reseting f after the first verify invocation: `Mockito.reset(f)` ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no bug. The implementors of the library thinks multiple invocations in a single test method is not a best practice. There two choices to overcome this issue:

1. **Good one:** use separate tests for each `f.bar()` invocations and test them independently.
2. **Not a good one:** use `Mockito.reset(f)` before the second invocation. It resets the state of the spied `f`; for instance if you have inserted a mock call like `doThrow(new Exception).when(f).bar(45)`, it is reset after the `reset()` call. But the second verify works with `times(1)`.