# How to perform unit testing on void function with coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to unit testing. 
I am trying to perform unit testing on the below code

```
public void send(Map<String, List<Integer>> mapOf){

     mapOf.forEach((k ,v) -> {
         v.stream().forEach(o ->{
             myList.add(o)
             message.push(o);
         });
     });
    }
```

```
message.push(o), pushes data to the database. <br/>
```

How can I Unit test this method?

Comment: I do not fully understand your example: What is myList used for?  Is the code just writing all Integers to the data base, with the keys being ignored?  And, why do you mention coverage in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would Mock this message obejct and [Verify](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_verifying_behavior.htm) how mamy times it was called .

More informations and example you can find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify)

[Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14889951/6221731)