# Verifying the number of times the method was called using Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am new to mockito...
What I am trying to do is to use mockito and System.print out the number of times that a certain method was called...

For example,
The numer of times that the Class.doSomething() was called: n times

I guess we need to use verify() or Invocations but I have been searching up about this for hours but have not found any solutions...

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. assume that you have a class Sample With method doSomehting

```
public class Sample {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

2. in JUnit test case, verify the method was called n times using Mockito

```
@Test
public void testMockitoTimes {
    Sample sample = Mockito.mock(Sample.class);
    sample.doSomething(); ..... 
    Mockito.verfiy(sample, Mockito.times(n)).doSomething();
}
```

3. there is a lot of link that you could refer, such as [verify-a-method-is-called-two-times-with-mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889951/how-to-verify-a-method-is-called-two-times-with-mockito-verify)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can print a message each time the method is called. You can add the log on the production code or use proxy on the method for add logging layer.

```
@Mock
private MockedObject mockedObject;


verify(mockedObject,times(2)).doSomething();
```