# Mockito mockingDetails.getInvocations() question

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, invocation

What I am trying to do is to print out the number of times that a certain method was called using Mockito.

When I do the following:

```
 int counter =
    Mockito.mockingDetails(myDependency)
        .getInvocations()
        .size();
System.out.println( counter );
```

it prints out all the methods invoked on the mock, however, I want to print out the counter for only one specific method, so if I try,

```
 int counter =
    Mockito.mockingDetails(myDependency.doSomething())
        .getInvocations()
        .size();
System.out.println( counter );
```

it occurs an error, saying that

Argument passed to Mockito.mockingDetails() should be a mock, but is null!

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you try to get that information and what do you want to do with it? If you want to test that a method has been invoked a certain number of times you would use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14890172). If it fails, you will also see the number of times the method has actually been called.

Comment: "Argument passed to Mockito.mockingDetails() should be a mock, but is null!" ..sounds comprehensible (and credible ..as i know mockito)

Comment: ..it should be `Mockito.mockingDetails(myDependency)...` ...which would give you information refering to the "whole mock" (object), if you need information about `doSomething()`, you can issue/iterate [getStubbings()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getStubbings())

Answer (score 0):

You can play with reflection:

```
MockingDetails mockingDetails = Mockito.mockingDetails(myDependency);

Method doSomethingMethod = mockingDetails.getMockHandler()
    .getMockSettings()
    .getTypeToMock()
    .getMethod("doSomething"); //here you can also pass the arguments of this method

long counter = mockingDetails.getInvocations()
    .stream()
    .filter(invocation -> invocation.getMethod().equals(doSomethingMethod))
    .count();
```

Note that in order to get an object of `Method` class, we can't simply call `myDependency.getClass().getMethod("doSomething")` because in this case `getClass()` would return Mockito's wrapper class generated in runtime with its own `Method` objects. So `equals` in filter would return `false` later.